# module to customization product in drupal commerce

Tags: 7, commerce

Is there any module to let my shop customers design their own t-shirt, mugs, caps, mouse pads. They can upload an image to t-shirt, back and front side, or select existing image from the logo categories, and they can also write their text on the template shirt.
and have below features

Features:

- Upload an image on the template t-shirt.
- List item
- Change t-shirt side, front or back.
- Select an Image from the existing logo categories, to put on the
- template t-shirt
- Write text on the template t-shirt
- Up to 4 text lines - New
- Change text size, color, font type

my shop is based on drupal commerce

anybody know  module to provide something like this features, or any idea that how can I implement it?

Comment: Related to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/114553/16495 ? :)

Comment: my question is related to it and it relate to my question, :)
@Mołot this is unlimited loop, it makes memory exhaust ;)

Comment: I haven't voted duplicates, I just see them as somehow similar and wanted to make sure they are two-way linked, mostly for benefit of people who happened to see the other one.

Comment: I think vote it to close is better, my question is with more explanation and more details

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [Commerce Customizable Products](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product)

> Drupal Commerce allows you to sell customizable products that require
>   customer input when added to the cart. Use cases for this
>   functionality include:

- Business cards that require contact information and a logo upload.
- Event registrations that require attendee information.
- Donations the allow the customer to specify a donation amount.

and especially for t-shirt design it is possible only through third party tools, we can integrate but it is not free, they have drupal support with their tool http://www.online-product-designer.com/online-advance-tshirt-design-tool.php and http://harboarts.com/shirtdesigner/

Comment: @zhilevan check this too https://drupal.org/project/commerce_dressing_room

Comment: I found this site created by drupal : http://www.whooptee.com/designer but I dont know what modules it used .

Comment: @zhilevan I found this plugin http://codecanyon.net/item/fancy-product-designer-jquery-plugin/3581183 based on this discussion http://www.drupalcommerce.org/questions/13414/integrate-httpcodecanyonnetitemfancy-product-designer-jquery-plugin3581183-drupal

Comment: thanks for your attention, the jquery's plugins http://fancyproductdesigner.com/jquery-plugin/ is great, but how can I use it in my drupal commerce site?

Comment: It is not free :(  .

Comment: @zhilevan I checked everywhere it is possible only through  third party tools, we can integrate but it is not free check this they have drupal support with their tool http://www.online-product-designer.com/online-advance-tshirt-design-tool.php and http://harboarts.com/shirtdesigner/ and https://www.freelancer.com/job-search/drupal-module-tshirt-designer/1/

Comment: good job man,which one you prefer that be easier to integrate with drupal commerce?

Comment: tnx for your attention, I think drupal need a module like this (design product module )

Answer (score 2):

I think the best bet for user customized products for Drupal Commerce is to integrate the open source fabricjs.com library. This can then export as an image, svg or json data.

I did a quick fiddle mock-up here for a basic demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cdn256L6/1/

Is anyone keen to implement this for Drupal 8 / Commerce 2.0?

If not, perhaps as interested parties we can start a chip-in to get this done?